# Export sleep data from S-Health

Tags: samsung, sleep, export

I am using a Samsung Galaxy Note 9 and a Galaxy watch to record sleep with the S-Health app.

Is there a way to export the data? I notice I can easily export heart rate data, however the sleep section doesn't offer the option.

I found the following question from a few years ago:
[Is it possible to export the S-Health data from a Samsung S6 into a usable data format?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/117112/is-it-possible-to-export-the-s-health-data-from-a-samsung-s6-into-a-usable-data)

However is there a way to get the sleep data without resorting to developer type solutions as above? Perhaps a 3rd party app the can connect to S-Health?

Answer (score 3):

It's not so convenient to do on a daily basis but you can export all your data from Samsung galaxy health.

1. In the top right corner click on the three dots
2. Choose settings
3. In the "Data" section choose "Download Personal data"
4. Click "Download" at the bottom of the screen
5. Verify your Samsung account password

It will download a bunch of csv files to My Files > Internal Storage > Samsung Health > Download > Samsunghealth_[your username]_[download date and time stamp].

One of them will be "com.samsung.health.sleep.[download date and time stamp].csv

Some of the information is useful, some is not.

Comment: Did they remove this option? I don't see the 3 dots.

Comment: They moved it.
1. On the home screen click on the 3 horizontal lines on the top left
2. On the screen that slides out from the left side, click on the settings wheel (looks like a cog or gear wheel) on the top right.

Follow the above answer starting from step 3.

Comment: On my device, they went inside "Internal memory > Android > data > com.sec.android.app.shealth"